# Cycle with interval stops acting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have been trying to learn some basics of web designing involving some simple HTML, CSS, JS/Jquery and have been coming up to certain obstacles that I haven't been able to find a way to work around.

One of the things I'm trying to implement is rotating a small number of divs. At the lack of some proper manner for it, what I rigged up was to .toggle off one of them while toggling on another div that was hidden from page load.

Not the prettiest thing, but it kind of works though oddly enough it only works twice before for some reason the cycle stops working.

```
function moveSide(){
    var intervalId;
    var childCount = 2;
    var preLast = childCount + 2;
    var newLast = childCount + 3;

    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        $(".column:nth-of-type(" + childCount + ")").toggle("slide", function(){
            $(".column:nth-of-type(" + preLast + ")").removeClass("last").delay(1, function(){
                $(".column:nth-of-type(" + newLast + ")").addClass("last").delay(1).toggle("slide", function(){
                    childCount++;
                    preLast = childCount + 2;
                    newLast = childCount + 3;
                    //alert(childCount);
                });
            });
        });
    },5000);
}
```

I'm not sure if using `nth-of-type` is the right choice, but it seemed to be allowing me to pick amongst the divs. `childCount` is to pick which div is to be the first to be toggled off, `pre(vious)Last` is to identify what was the last div of those displayed in order to remove a class used for some properties, `newLast` is to identify the div that will become visible and give it the class to add CSS properties.

The alert cycle runs twice entirely (increasing `childCount`), but doesn't process a third time.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is it a menu or something? Can you find an example of another website doing it? By the looks of it, it's overly complicated. Also, could you supply a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or some HTML?

Comment: It's probably much more complicated than what it needs to be certainly as I'm probably not tackling this the best way Jquery has to offer. I tried to set up something at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yy797gjs/3/) but something seems to be lacking as it's not working, though it's pretty much what I tried to setup on my site.  I don't really remember any specific site that uses this so I can't give it as example, but the idea is that 3 divs are always visible, one toggles off, another one toggles in from a group of 7 or so, and eventually they'd rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't now, if it's my not cured cold or the fact, that i just got up a few hours ago, but i don't understand your code.

what i understand, is what you want to achieve - and i suggest another method:

```
$(".column:gt(0)").hide(); //first of all, hide all columns but the first one

setInterval(function() { 
$('.column:first')                //select the first column
  .toggle("slide")                //slide it out
  .next().next()                  //select the 3rd column
  .toggleClass("last")            //remove class "last"
  .next()                         //select first invisible column    
  .toggleClass("last")            //add class last
  .toggle("slide")                //slide it in
  .end().end().end()              //end the chain, to reselect the first element 
             // since we used .next() three times, we have to end it three times
  .appendTo('#column-content');   //move the first element inside the dom to the end
},  5000);
```

your interval should be running infinite now - always sliding out the first element, sliding in the next element end appending the first element to the end. therefore, the current element is always the first one...
see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sv5j85df/2/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If nothing else it certainly seems a much simpler way to do things, however when trying to use the code as you pasted, the first column is toggling out and in each cycle. My intention is as well to have 3 columns displaying at a time, but I can work around that one, it's just that as is the first column keeps being called back, which according to your code comments shouldn't be happening.

Comment: could you post the relevant html markup into your code? or provide a jsfiddle? i haven't yet tested it with the toggle slide, but used the fadeIn/fadeOut functions. just thought, that it may work though - since you only change the animation. with a jsfiddle, i could check via console, if the dom get's handled correctly.

Comment: next thing - if you want to display 3 columns at a time - how should the toggling take space? do you want to toggle all 3 shown columns, or only slideout the first, move the second to first position, the third to second position and the new shown 4th col at third position?

Comment: Earlier I had put up this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sv5j85df/) which is the tidbit i want to affect. tried it over at jsbin and it was "functional", and behaved the same way as in the full thing. my jumbled code only works twice, yours only toggled the first element. If something else is needed do let me know, I'm not exactly aware of what information I need or not to provide in these things.

Comment: well, thanks for the fiddle, now i know, why it didn't work for you. have you ever heard of selectors? you just copied my code - and my append function used a selector, that didn't exisdt in your markup. that's why i asked for your html. i build my chain in your fiddle, used the correct selectors - take a look at it (link is inside the solution)

Comment: the animations are really jumpy that way. this is because, the first two columns are only replaced inside the dom, and the last column slides in. i also don't know, if chaining like that is really the right way... but it works^^

Comment: Thank you very much! Frankly after being several days without an answer I decided to look for more possible solutions (especially after you having mentioned .appendTo). I did mange to get the thing working before coming peek in here again (only to see you had responded 3 hours earlier), but this is still the cleaner solution and at least I now understand a bit more about this. So thank you again.

Comment: you're welcome ;) been offline for some days - that's why it took so much time...